# NSIS script help-install without killing explorer

Tags: nsis

When I tried to un-install and install an executable foo.exe, Im geting the below error

```
Error opening file for writing
click abort to stop the installation
```

I could find that some files were failed to get deleted while un-installation.
And by using process explorer I can see that `explorer.exe` has still reference to some dlls of foo.exe even after unregistering them.

and killing the explorer.exe and re-start it again while un-installation solves the issue. (thru NSIS installation script).

or by setting rebook ok flag in script and ask user to re-start his machine before installing foo.exe again.

I don't think its a good solution to ask user to reboot his machine after un-installation .

Can anyone help me on  how can I make sure that my installation goes fine  instead of  restarting explorer.exe

Comment: How are you executing the uninstaller?

Comment: I have the un-installer. Im executing with all the permission with UAC pluggin.. its not the issue with my UAC .(using XP)

Comment: I actually wasn't thinking of UAC, but rather your execution method not waiting for the uninstaller to properly finish and only continuing to the installer when it's really done. It's a very common issue with NSIS uninstallers.

Comment: HI kichik , I was reading one of your forum comments..about moving the dlls to temp and rename ..thats ok..I use   RMDir /r /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR" asthe last line of un-install script. this is after calling exec wait on registered dlls..deleteregkey everything..

Comment: Still not what I meant... :) http://nsis.sourceforge.net/When_I_use_ExecWait_uninstaller.exe_it_doesn%27t_wait_for_the_uninstaller

Comment: sorry for bein pig head.. but I dont use execwait I create unstaller in a  Section -Post
        WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe" and from short cut I call this un-installer CreateShortCut  "$SMPROGRAMS\Foo\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe" 0

Comment: So you're executing the uninstaller through Explorer? If that's the case, disregard my comment.

Comment: Are these .dll's shell extensions registered in the registry?

Comment: Hi Anders  you are right..these are shell extensions..registered

Answer (score 1):

For registered shell extensions there is really no clean way to delete the dll's other than forcing a reboot (Or log-off if they are registered in HKCU\Software\Classes)

If that is not good enough you basically have two options:

- Rename the .dll and delete it later
- `<HACKALERT>`Inject a thread that calls [CoFreeUnusedLibraries()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679712%28VS.85%29.aspx) into every process that has your dll loaded`</HACKALERT>`

Just killing and restarting explorer is not really an option since you don't know if some other program is also using your shell extension.

Comment: Anders, tried renaming of residues which exists afer un-installation but couldnt succeed in that. can you provide me with any sample code snippet..